# Example of a power of 3 which is close to a power of 2 (Related to music theory and Superparticular ratios)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, music-theory, abc-conjecture

I'm looking for a power of 3 close to a power of 2.

Let's say,
what is $(n,m)$ such that $$\left|\frac{2^n}{3^m}-1\right| = \min\left \{\left|\frac{2^i}{3^j}-1 \right|,  1\leq i,j\leq 20\right\} \quad ?$$

#### Why?

The idea is to understand the intervals between musical notes. Any link on this subject is welcomed (I don't know music theory but I'm interested).

Comment: $\dfrac{2^1}{3^{20}}$ sounds good? (no pun intended :)
But if you want a power of $3$ which is close to a power of $2$ maybe you wanted $$ \min\left \{|3^j-2^i|,  1\leq i,j\leq 20\right\} $$

Comment: @Raffaele I just understood your good (intended!) pun. Another way to see the issue is to say that's about two superpowers that should be equilibrated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want $2^i \approx 3^j$ with $i,j \in \mathbb N$

(preferably $1 \leq i,j \leq 20$).

Take the logarithm (in any base) of both sides: $$i \log(2) \approx j \log(3).$$

Thus the issue is now to obtain a good **rational approximation**

$$\underbrace{\dfrac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}}_{N}\approx \dfrac{i}{j}$$

Such rational approximations are obtained as the so-called "convergents" of the continued fraction expansion of number $N$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction):

$$N=a_0+\tfrac{1}{a_1+\tfrac{1}{{a_2+\tfrac{1}{\cdots}}}}$$

with $(a_0; a_1, a_3, \cdots )=(1;1,1,2,2,3,1,5,2,23,2,2,1,55,1,...).$

with successive convergents:

$$ i/j = 3/2, \ 5/3, \ 8/5, \ 11/7, \ 19/12, \ 46/29, \ 65/41, \ 84/53, ...$$

$$317/200,\ 401/253, \ 485/306, \ 569/359, \ 1054/665...$$

(that can be found in (https://oeis.org/A254351/internal)).

Good convergents are obtained by (in plain terms) "stopping just before a big $a_k$".

If the "big $a_k$" (!) is 3, one gets :

> $$\dfrac{19}{12} \approx 1.5833 \ \ \ \text{of} \ \ \ N = 1.5850...$$
>
> Thus a good tradeoff is to take $i=19$ and $j=12$.

This is connected to the  "Pythagorician comma". (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_comma).

Very related : ([http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~mrubinst/tuning/12.html](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Emrubinst/tuning/12.html))

Comment: I know the definition of continued fractions, but I never thought it had a link to rational approximation.

Comment: That makes senses since there are 12 musical notes.

Comment: see as well (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11669)

Comment: Related (http://andrewduncan.net/cmt/)

Comment: Each term in the continued fraction ($a_n$) corresponds to a convergent. You are giving the "semiconvergents" when you include $\frac53$ and $\frac{11}7$. For  their denominators, these are not as close to the number being approximated as the convergents.

Comment: @robjon I understand.

Comment: On paper I calculated $2^{19}/3^{12}-1\approx 0.013483.$

Answer (score 6):

Here I have written different things in different parts; the **first** and **third** are related to each other:

---

**Irrelevant to the main question** (For those who are interested in the connection between music theory and powers of primes): Years ago when I was writing this answer, I did not know about its connection with music theory. This morning I received a notification for an up-vote to this question (That's why I added this information). 3 or 4 months ago, I got information about the relationship between music theory ([Superparticular ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superparticular_ratio)) and prime powers $2$, $3$, etc.; the links to which I will briefly share here:

1. [Størmer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem)
2. [ABC, High Quality Commas, and Epimericity](https://web.archive.org/web/20121008052150/http://xenharmonic.wikispaces.com/ABC%2C+High+Quality+Commas%2C+and+Epimericity) (The [original link](http://xenharmonic.wikispaces.com/ABC%2C+High+Quality+Commas%2C+and+Epimericity) has expired)
3. [A Weaker Version of the ABC Conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112133/a-weaker-version-of-the-abc-conjecture)

Just read the first link (I mean [Størmer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem)), to understand the connection between music theory ([Superparticular ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superparticular_ratio) and ...) and the powers of prime numbers through Pell equations.

Also, you can see the contents of the link in the "Internet Web Archive" in the image below (just to be sure, if this link becomes unavailable in the future):
[image]

(I still do not even understand why, in the question, why we consider the upper limit to be $20$? and set this restriction? Perhaps for a practical exercise?)

---

---

---

---

---

---

**Related to the main question**:

**Lemma**:
Let $\alpha, \beta$ be linearly independent
over rationals $\mathbb{Q}$;
i.e. $\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta} \notin \mathbb{Q}$.
Then the group generated by $\alpha, \beta$ is **dense** in $\mathbb{Q}$;
i.e.
$ 
\{ i\alpha+j\beta \ | \ i,j \in \mathbb{Z} \} = 
\{ i\alpha-j\beta \ | \ i,j \in \mathbb{Z} \} 
$
is **dense** in $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

---

Now let $\alpha:=\log2$ and $\beta:=\log3$,
note that
$\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha}=\dfrac{\log3}{\log2}=\log_23 \notin \mathbb{Q}$;
so if we let $i, j$ varies arbitrary in $\mathbb{N}$,
then
the phrase $i\alpha-j\beta$
will become as small as we want;

i.e. in more mathematical discipline we can say:
for every $0 < \delta \in \mathbb{R}$
there exist $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$
such that $0 < i\alpha-j\beta < \delta$.

---

Note that:
$$ 
10^{i\alpha-j\beta}=
\dfrac{10^{i\alpha}}{10^{j\beta}}=
\dfrac{(10^{\alpha})^{i}}{(10^{\beta})^{j}}=
\dfrac{2^i}{3^j}
$$

So we can conclude that:
for every $0 < \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$
there exist $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$
such that $1 < \dfrac{2^i}{3^j} < 1+ \epsilon$.

So ignoring some mathematical disciplines we can say:
if we let $i, j$ varies arbitrary in $\mathbb{N}$,
then
the phrase $\dfrac{2^i}{3^j}$
will become as close to $1$ as we want.

---

---

We can restase some similar facts about
$-\delta < i\alpha-j\beta < 0$ and
$-\delta < i\alpha-j\beta < \delta$;
also for
$1- \epsilon < \dfrac{2^i}{3^j} < 1$ and
$1- \epsilon < \dfrac{2^i}{3^j} < 1+ \epsilon$; but it does not matters.

---

---

---

---

---

---

I have seen this problem before:

unsolved problems in number theory by *Richard K. Guy*;
$F$(None of the above);
$F23$(Small differences between powers of $2$ and $3$.) :

Problem $1$ of Littlewood's book
asks how small $3^n — 2^m$ can be in comparison with $2^m$.
He gives as an example
$$ 
\dfrac{3^{12}} {2^{19}} = 1+ 
\dfrac{ 7153 } {524288} \approx 1+ 
\dfrac{   1  } {  73  } 
\qquad
\text{ (the ratio of } D^{\sharp} \text{ to } E^{\flat}). 
$$
[Where $\sharp$ and $\flat$ stands for dièse and Bémol.]

The first few convergents to the continued fraction (see $F20$)
$$ 
log_23= 
 1+\tfrac{1}
{1+\tfrac{1}
{1+\tfrac{1}
{2+\tfrac{1}
{2+\tfrac{1}
{3+\tfrac{1}
{1+\tfrac{1}
{\cdots}
}
}
}
}
}
}
$$

for $\log 3$ to the base $2$ are:
$$ 
\dfrac{ 1}{ 1}, 
\dfrac{ 2}{ 1}, 
\dfrac{ 3}{ 2}, 
\dfrac{ 8}{ 5}, 
\dfrac{19}{12}, 
\dfrac{65}{41}, 
\dfrac{84}{53}, 
\dots 
$$
so **Victor Meally** observed that
the $\color{Blue}{\text{octave}}$ may conveniently be partitioned
into $12$, $41$ or $53$ intervals,
and that the system of temperament with $53$ degrees
is due to ***Nicolaus Mercator***
($1620-1687$; not **Gerhardus**, $1512-1594$, of map projection fame).

**Ellison** used the **Gel'fond-Baker** method to show that

$$ 
|2^x-3^y| > 2^x e^{\dfrac{-x}{10}} 
\qquad \text{for} \qquad x > 27 
$$

and **Tijdeman** used it to show that
there is a $c \geq 1$
such that $2^x - 3^y > \dfrac{2^x}{x^c}$.

**Croft** asks the corresponding question for $n! — 2^m$. $ \ \ \cdots$

That was the exact text from the book,
note that the pair $(m,n)$
has been used in the reversed order in that book
versus this question has been asked in this site!

At the end of section $F23$;
there are four refrences as follows:

- F. Beukers, Fractional parts of powers of rationals, Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos.
  Soc., $90(1981) 13-20$; MR $83$g:$10028$.
- A. K. Dubitskas, A lower bound on the value of $||(3/2)^k||$ (Russian), Uspekhi Mat.
  Nauk, $45(1990) 153-154$; translated in Russian Math. Surveys, $45(1990) 
  163-164$; MR $91$k:$11058$.
- W. J. Ellison, Recipes for solving diophantine problems by Baker's method, S6m.
  Thiorie Nombms, $1970-71$, Exp. No. $11$, C.N.R.S. Talence, $1971$.
- R. Tijdeman, On integers with many small factors, Compositio Math., $26 (1973) 
  319-330$.
- I have found an article by **Kurt Mahler**
  with the same name as the first one [here](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/mahler/docs/051.pdf).

---

Also in page $14$ of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0312440.pdf) of **Michel Waldschmidt**;
you can find something.

Comment: Very interesting !

Comment: As you are very competent in number theory, here is a question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4418458/305862 which hasn't received a satisfying answer. Could you have a look ?

Answer (score 2):

The continued fraction for $\frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}$ is 
$$
1;1,1,2,2,3,1,5,2,23,2,2,1,1,55,1,4,3,1,1,\dots
$$
The convergents are
$$
\frac11,\frac21,\frac32,\frac85,\frac{19}{12},\frac{65}{41},\frac{84}{53},\frac{485}{306},\frac{1054}{665},\frac{24727}{15601},\frac{50508}{31867},\frac{125743}{79335},\frac{176251}{111202},\frac{301994}{190537},\frac{16785921}{10590737},\frac{17087915}{10781274},\frac{85137581}{53715833}, \frac{272500658}{171928773},\frac{357638239}{225644606}, \frac{630138897}{397573379},\cdots
$$
This gives a number of "close" approximations. For example, the best with exponents between $1$ and $20$, is
$$
\left|\frac{2^{19}}{3^{12}}-1\right|=0.01345963145485576
$$
This gives the approximation $2^{19/12}=2.9966$. Since their are $12$ half-steps to the octave, this approximation is very useful.

Comment: A certain number of  convergents are missing in your list : $5/3$, $11/7, 46/29...$

Comment: @JeanMarie: are you talking about [convergents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents), or [semiconvergents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Semiconvergents), which are not as close as convergents for their denominators?